# What is the difference between Yizkor and Eil Molei prayers?

Tags: tefilla, soul, nusach-ashkenaz, yizkor

Of course, they differ in text, but in terms of their meaning, they are exactly the same. In fact, these are stylistically different two versions of the same prayer.

So can Eil Molei replace Yizkor and vice versa? For example, Western Ashkenazim do not have Eil Molei.

Comment: Most congregations say Kel Molei by Yizkor as well

Comment: Are there communities where they read Eil Molei instead of Yizkor? @Chatzkel